# How do I interpolate a field that is divergence-free and curl-free at the same time?

Tags: interpolation, rbf-kernel, divergence

A magnetic field is divergence free. At the points where there is no current, and no changing electric field, it is also curl free.

There exist divergence-free and curl-free RBF kernels, and I could use either. But are there kernels which are div-free and curl-free at the same time?

Comment: Can you exhibit an example that is not constant?

Comment: Take a gradient of any harmonic function. E.g. gradient of any of the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics. It's curl-free because it's a gradient and div-free because the original function satisfies Laplace equation.